# Broadcast across a VDE switch

Tags: networking, linux-networking, virtual-network

I created a simple VDE Switch as per:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082722/how-do-i-create-virtual-ethernet-devices-in-linux

To paraphrase that question, the setup is:

```
sudo vde_switch -tap tap0 -tap tap1
sudo ifconfig tap0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
sudo ifconfig tap1 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Broadcasting is recognised on the interfaces:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.0.255.255
    inet6 fe80::3402:41ff:fecc:97ad  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 36:02:41:cc:97:ad  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6  bytes 468 (468.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2086  bytes 173190 (169.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.0.255.255
    inet6 fe80::bced:b3ff:fec0:13a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether be:ed:b3:c0:13:a8  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2086  bytes 173190 (169.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6  bytes 468 (468.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

However, I can't seem to broadcast over this network.
e.g.

```
$ sudo ping -b 10.0.255.255
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 10.0.255.255 (10.0.255.255) from 10.16.0.1 tap0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
```

I would have expected to see replies from *both* 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2.

Ping broadcasting is enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts 
0
```

What could I have done wrong?  Does VDE/TUN allow for broadcasting?